# 404 not found with flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I tried to run this code but the webpage shows 404 not found flask link:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/hello") def index(): return("heloooo")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
@app.route("/hello") def index(): return("heloooo")
```

does not make any sense in Python, instead use it like this:

```
@app.route("/hello")
def index():
    return("heloooo")
```

Secondly, you can't use `name` variable if you didn't define it anywhere. What you meant to use is `__name__` and `__main__` and also with correct indentation:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

To wrap it up, this is the code you should try your `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello` with:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello")
def index():
    return("heloooo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If this doesn't work, then you should post exact error.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello")
def index(): return("heloooo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have used your code. Its running perfectly. might be issue with your run time environment. I am running same program with my windows machine. follow to setup https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/.

logs:

> - Serving Flask app "test.py"  * Environment: production    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production
>   deployment.    Use a production WSGI server instead.  * Debug mode:
>   off  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2020 20:33:09] "?[33mGET / HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2020 20:33:10] "?[33mGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2020 20:33:19] "?[33mGET /hellp HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2020 20:33:24] "?[33mGET /hell0 HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2020 20:33:29] "?[37mGET /hello HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -